# What are all the sources of Constitution damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

Looking to make a Constitution Obliteration Build. Sort of a one-trick pony, but that's fine.

Things I've found so far:

1. Venom Domain grants Venomous Saliva, which allows Swift Action application of a CON poison to a weapon. This poison is non-magical poison.
2. Venom Domain grants the Poison Spell earlier than any other capable caster (as early as level 5). This poison is a magical poison.
3. Touch of Slime afflicts enemies with a lesser Green Slime, dealing 1d3 CON damage. This is a disease affliction.
4. Purchased injury poisons (not ideal because they're expensive)

The above four sources stack with each other. If all of the first three are affecting the same target, that's 2d3+1 CON damage every turn. That's between 3 and 7 CON per round with an average of 5.

I still want to push the limit further. Without resorting to purchased poisons, is there any other source of CON damage (not CON penalties as they do not reduce CON past 1) available to a player? Keep it Paizo only.

Answer (score 3):

1. A barbarian can use the [Disembowling Tusks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/disemboweling-tusks) L10 rage power.
2. You could use [monster summoning](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster/summon-monster-1-statblocks) (~1st level spell) to summon vipers, which have CON poison.
3. You could cast [rain of frogs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/rain-of-frogs) (~3rd level spell) and douse people in CON damaging frogs.
4. You could have the [nanite](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/nanite-bloodline-sorcerer-bloodline) sorcerer bloodline.
5. You could have various [animal companions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions) that do CON damage, like the puffball fungus, giant gila monster, giant leech, viper, or stingray, or one that gives a disease like filth fever that then does CON damage.
6. Any of the many disease-giving abilities that give a disease that does CON damage (filth fever being the most common)
7. Create any of the many undead that do CON damage, or that give filth fever which in turn gives CON damage.
8. Summon/bind any of the various other outsiders etc. that do CON damage.
9. Be a trapsmith rogue (or other class) that quickly makes traps that do CON damage. Or a [trapper ranger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo---ranger-archetypes/trapper/ranger-traps).
10. Sorcerer [serpentine bloodline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/serpentine-bloodline), den of vipers class feature.
11. Druid [serpent shaman](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/serpent-shaman) bite attack.
12. Witch with [blight hex](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes---3rd-party-publishers/hexes/common-hexes/hex-blight-su).
13. Grippli alchemist with [deadly excretions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-grippli/bogborn-alchemist-alchemist-grippli/deadly-excretions-ex) discovery
14. Lots of magic items

Probably many more. Without deciding on a class/race/level/gp budget this is really still too broad to be answerable and turns into an endless list; after going through this exercise I've convinced myself the question needs to be put on hold again for better refinement.

Comment: I think you could have dropped the mic at #3.